# How to stream RTMP locally

Tags: video-streaming, rtmp

I have developed a application that takes a RTMP feed and and displays the image.

Just to test locally how can i create a rtmp feed which can be given to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up something like [Nimble Streamer](https://wmspanel.com/nimble/live_streaming) or [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/) as a simple RTMP server.

Then the simplest way to generate an RTMP stream and send it to the RTMP server is the great open source project [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).